# Sending PHP Form Data

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create an online order form using PHP.

I've already got it working using PHP Checkboxes for each item.

But now I want to remove the Checkboxes - replacing them with a Quantity box and a Message box for each item.

Here is how I currently have my order form setup with checkboxes (I removed the checkbox from the 1st item "Mexican Tortas," and added the Quantity & Message boxes as an example).

What is the best way to go about this, so that only the items that have data entered into the Quantity box (and Message box) will be sent to my email?

**HTML:**

```
<div class ="item_left">
<img src="images/mexicantortas.jpg" border="2" width="200px" height="150px"><br>
Mexican Torta - $8.50<input name="item" type="hidden" value="Mexican Torta"/><br>
How Many? <input name="quantity" type="text" style="width: 20px; height: 12px;"/><br>
<input name="message" type="text" value="Enter special order instructions here..."   style="max-width: 200px; height: 30px;"/>
</div><!-- ITEM_LEFT -->

<div class ="item_center">
<img src="images/fishsandwich.jpg" border="2" width="200px" height="150px"><br/>
Fish Sandwich - $8.50<input name="item" type="hidden" value="Fish Sandwich"/><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Fish Sandwich"><br/>
</div><!-- ITEM_CENTER -->

<div class ="item_right">
<img src="images/hamburgers.jpg" border="2" width="200px" height="150px"><br/>
Hamburger w/ Fries - $7.00
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="Hamburger"><br/>
</div><!-- ITEM_RIGHT -->
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$to = "test@websitehere.com"; 
$subject = "Form Tutorial";
$name_field = $_POST['name'];
$email_field = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$option = $_POST['radio'];
$dropdown = $_POST['drop_down'];

foreach($_POST['check'] as $value) {
$check_msg .= "Checked: $value\n";
}

$body = "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n $check_msg
    Option:$option\n    Drop-Down: $dropdown\n Message:\n $message\n";

echo "Data has been submitted to $to!";
mail($to, $subject, $body);

 } else {
echo "blarg!";
}
?>
```

Comment: I am assuming quantity box = select box and message box = text field?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you have a bunch of things with the same name not allowing you to distinguish them on the server side. Second, are you wanting each email to send you just 1 item or more than 1 item if they choose more than 1 item?

Either way what you are wanting to do I think is to validate and check if the values are equal to "" or 0 depending on your select box. Second, take these variables and populate them into an array. Then, you could loop through your array appending the items to your $message using html to separate them.

Answer (score 0):

Mind you, this is just something quick I typed up in about 10 mins, so I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but, it gets the job done.

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $to = "test@websitehere.com"; 
    $subject = "Form Tutorial";
    $name_field = $_POST['name'];
    $email_field = $_POST['email'];

    $order = array();
    foreach($_POST['item'] as $item => $name) {
        if ($_POST['quantity_'.$name] > 0) {
            $add_order = array('pretty'=>$_POST['pretty-name_'.$name],'qty'=>$_POST['quantity_'.$name],'message'=>$_POST['message_'.$name]);
            array_push($order,$add_order);
        }
    }

    $body = "From: $name_field\nE-Mail: $email_field\n";

    $body .= "Their Order:\n";
    foreach ($order as $item){
        $body .= "--".$item['qty']."x ".$item['pretty']."\n
        Extra: ".$item['message']."\n\n";
    }

    echo "Data has been submitted to $to!";
    mail($to, $subject, $body);
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<div class ="item_left">

Mexican Torta - $8.50<input name="item[]" type="hidden" value="torta"/>
<input name="pretty-name_torta" type="hidden" value="Mexican Torta"/><br>
How Many? <input name="quantity_torta" type="text" /><br>
<input name="message_torta" type="text" value="Enter special order instructions here..." />
</div><!-- ITEM_LEFT -->
<br />
<div class ="item_center">

Fish Sandwich - $8.50<input name="item[]" type="hidden" value="fish"/>
<input name="pretty-name_fish" type="hidden" value="Fish Sandwhich"/><br>
How Many? <input name="quantity_fish" type="text" /><br>
<input name="message_fish" type="text" value="Enter special order instructions here..." />
</div><!-- ITEM_CENTER -->
<br />
<div class ="item_right">

Hamburger w/ Fries - $7.00<input name="item[]" type="hidden" value="hamburger"/>
<input name="pretty-name_hamburger" type="hidden" value="Hamburger"/><br>
How Many? <input name="quantity_hamburger" type="text" /><br>
<input name="message_hamburger" type="text" value="Enter special order instructions here..." />
</div><!-- ITEM_RIGHT -->
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Order" />
</form>
```

OUTPUT: (Similar to)

```
Their Order:
--22x Mexican Torta
Extra: Enter special order instructions here...

--1x Fish Sandwhich
Extra: Lots of stuff

--2x Hamburger
Extra: Mmmm Fries
```

Jared is right. You need to have a way to distinguish between the different items. Hence why I added a extra hidden input in there.

Long story short, Every item gets put into an array. PHP goes through this array and picks out what has a quantity value greater than 0. If it has, add that items info into a second array. The last half of this, goes through that new array, and makes it look all nice and pretty for you.

If you need me to clarify or fix anything, lemme know.

EDIT: Went ahead and added it into the mail function (boredom).

PS: I noticed you were using unsanitized varables. I probably shouldn't need to, but I will say it anyways. Make sure you are checking and cleaning user input before you do much with it. Probably not that big of a deal here, but it could still turn bad in certain situations.